# How to generate sulphuric acid vapour to test an analyzer?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy, gas-phase-chemistry

We have a UV gas analyzer we want to test to see if it reads gas phase $\ce{H2SO4}$. How can we safely produce less than $\pu{5 ppm}~\ce{H2SO4}$ as a spike test to see if the analyzer sees the spectra?

Comment: Perhaps heat anhydrous calcium sulfate mixed with silica. That generates sulfur trioxide plus calcium silicate. The sulfur trioxide plus water vapor gives the sulfuric acid. Maybe just use fresh Drierite (TM) and silica gel (the chromatographers always have it).

Comment: This [PDF](http://www.personal.psu.edu/mrh318/Gmitro-Vermeulen-AICE-1964.pdf) from psu.edu  contains graphical data about H2SO4 partial pressure at various temperatures